# Gmail API how to get labels ThreadsUnread

Tags: gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

how can i to get labels ThreadsUnread when excuting LabelsResource.ListRequest?

trying to get the ThreadsUnread property when i'm excuting the Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest
but it comes with null value.

This is my code:

```
     Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest labelReq = service.Users.Labels.List("me");

    IList<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Label> labels = labelReq.Execute().Labels;
```

what do i need to ask in the  request   the `ThreadsUnread`  or `MessagesUnread` value?

There is a property in the request that called "fields".
it can be set with a string. but where can i find what is the options of that string?

Comment: i found the syntax of the "fields" property. "labels(name,id,messagesTotal)". i dont get an error what says the syntax is fine. but i'm not getting the result of the total messages

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing (March, 2019), you cannot get counts when doing a list. You have to subsequently request the details of each label to get the detail. Very slow, costly and frankly unnecessary. The equivalent Microsoft Graph API doesn't have this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Users.labels.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get?authuser=1#try-it). In the try-it section do this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/labels/id
```

userId:
me

id:
INBOX

and execute, the response would looke something like:

```
{
 "id": "INBOX",
 "name": "INBOX",
 "messageListVisibility": "hide",
 "labelListVisibility": "labelShow",
 "type": "system",
 "messagesTotal": 1808,
 "messagesUnread": 1610,
 "threadsTotal": 454,
 "threadsUnread": 323
}
```

and there's the `"threadsUnread": 323` you're looking for.

Comment: before asking, try.

Comment: it works! thanks. but i still prefer to get it when querying the labels list.